How to set server name in kubespawner in jupyterhub notebook in GKE
import json
import os
from kubespawner import KubeSpawner


class CustomKubeSpawner(KubeSpawner):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def load_config(self):
    config_file_path = "/srv/jupyterhub/profiles.json"  # Update this to your file path
    if os.path.exists(config_file_path):
        with open(config_file_path) as f:
            self.all_lab_config = json.load(f)
    else:
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"Configuration file not found: {config_file_path}")

async def start(self):
    self.load_config()
    auth_state = await self.user.get_auth_state() if hasattr(self.user, 'get_auth_state') else None

    if auth_state:
        server = auth_state.get("user", {}).get("guid", "NoServerFound")
        if server == "NoServerFound":
            raise Exception("No server details found in auth state")
        labtype = auth_state.get("user", {}).get("labtype", "nonotebook")
    else:
        raise Exception("Auth state error:{}")

    print(f"---\nLabtype:{labtype}\nguid:{server}\n---")
    print(f"{self.user.name}")
    # Create a unique identifier using user and server names
    username = f"{self.user.name}".replace(" ", "")
    self.environment['JUPYTERHUB_SERVER_NAME'] = f"{server}"
    self.pod_name = f"{labtype}-{username}-{server}"
    self.server.name = f"{server}"
    self.storage_pvc_ensure = True
    print(self.all_lab_config)
    # Set configuration based on labtype from profiles.json
    self.lab_config = self.all_lab_config.get(labtype, "tagger")
    print(self.lab_config)
    self.image = self.lab_config.get("notebook_image", "jupyter/unknown")
    self.mem_guarantee = self.lab_config.get("mem_guarantee", "2G")
    self.cpu_guarantee = self.lab_config.get("cpu_guarantee", 0.5)

    env_vars = self.lab_config.get("env_variables", {})
    for key, value in env_vars.items():
        self.environment[key] = value

    # Additional pod configuration (e.g., node affinity) from profiles.json
    self.extra_pod_config = self.lab_config.get("extra_pod_config", {})

    # Define unique pvc_name_template and volume configuration
    self.storage_capacity = self.lab_config.get("storage_capacity", "20Gi")  # Default to 20Gi if not specified
    self.pvc_claim = f"claim-{username}"  # Ensures unique PVC name per user-server combination
    self.volume_name_template = f"{server}-vol"

    # Configure volumes and mounts
    self.volumes = [
        {
            "name": self.volume_name_template,
            "persistentVolumeClaim": {"claimName": self.pvc_name_template},
        }
    ]
    self.volume_mounts = [
        {
            'mountPath': '/home/jovyan',  # Mounts the volume at the specified path
            'name': self.volume_name_template
        }
    ]

    return await super().start()

The code works fine, it spawns a pod but the server name is not getting set it is empty.
When i query with jupytehrun api for a user using
url :{huburl}/hub/api/users/{username} using a get method
there is not server name available. it is empty

{'': {'name': '', 'last_activity': '2024-12-11T21:19:13.123000Z', 'started': '2024-12-11T21:18:45.435706Z', 'pending': None, 'ready': True, 'stopped': False, 'url': '/user/lokif75516e1/', 'user_options': {}, 'progress_url': '/hub/api/users/lokif75516e1/server/progress', 'state': {'pod_name': 'minimal-notebook-lokif75516e1--f75516e1-be3d-454d-xxxx-57e36fd8b9bd', 'namespace': 'jupynamespace', 'dns_name': 'jupyter-lokif75516e1.jupynamespace.svc.cluster.local'}}


auth_state is not defined in your code. auth_state (if it were defined) is used by your code to define server.

@DazWilkin, I missed the line in the code, are you suggesting the server parameter which  I get from auth_state is interfering with in built in server setting.

No, you've added the line where auth_state is defined so now we can understand the code better.
